# changing a for each loop into for loop

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I have the following code in VBA

```
Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim beanChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

XMLDOC.Load ("https://www.catch.api")

r = 4
Set userBeanList = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("/response/responseBody/responseList/item[recordType='TPI']")
For Each userbean In userBeanList
    For Each beanChild In userbean.ChildNodes
    If beanChild.nodeName = "catch" Then GoTo NextIteration

       Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 1) = beanChild.nodeName
         Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2) = beanChild.Text

  r = r + 1
NextIteration:
    Next beanChild
Next userbean
```

At the moment i am looping through all of the nodes and then in this case ignoring the node called "catch" and then going into the next iteration as i dont require that node or node value.
Rather than doing this how would i change my loop to one where i can just go directly to the nodes of interest and therefore not having to skip by iterations which just seems inefficient?

/////after help from parfait

```
Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim beanChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

XMLDOC.Load ("http://www.catch.api")

r = 4

Set userBeanList = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("/response/responseBody/responseList/item[recordType='TPI']/*[not(local-name)='catch']")
For Each userbean In userBeanList

       Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 1) = userbean.nodeName

         Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2) = userbean.Text

         r = r + 1

Next userbean
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188773/xpath-to-select-all-and-exclude-child-and-its-children

Comment: It might be a little more efficient to say it beanChild.nodeName <> "catch" then do stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider excluding it from the xpath expression. Below specifies any child with a `name()` or `local-name()` not equal to 'catch'. This even avoids the inner `For Each` loop on child nodes.

```
Set userBeanList = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("/response/responseBody/responseList" _
                                     & "/item[recordType='TPI']/*[not(local-name)='catch']")
```

Alternatively, with `self`

```
Set userBeanList = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("/response/responseBody/responseList" _
                                     & "/item[recordType='TPI']/*[not(self::catch)]")
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, how would I change the set if I had an or , for example 'catch' or 'reprive'

Comment: Simply add the `or` condition: `[not(self::catch or self::reprive)]`